# Ansible playbook error while running on - hosts:

Tags: ansible

write a task in main.yml to stop and start service in service "ssh" using service module in ansible.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: stop service
      service:
        name: ssh
        state: stopped
    - name: start service
      service:
        name: ssh
        state: started
```

when run it's giving below error

```
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /projects/challenge/localhost as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/projects/challenge/fresco_module/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be

---
- hosts: localhost
  ^ here
```

Comment: Could you please share the command you are using to run the given playbook.

Comment: ansible-playbook main.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using command module  was able to stop and start the service, using `sudo service ssh stop` and `sudo service ssh start` served my purpose.
was not able to do so with service module, still don't know about that

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be able to do SSH to localhost.
You can try,

```
ssh user@localhost date
```

You can create a hosts file and name it `hosts` and add the following content to it.

```
[localhost]
localhost

[localhost:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=user
ansible_ssh_pass=pass
ansible_sudo_pass=sudopass
```

And run the playbook as

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml
```

Comment: Since `only implicit localhost is available`, only the `local` connection will be used so there is no ssh connection involved. Redefining localhost as you do can be nice for tests using ssh against localhost but is not necessary and will not solve OP's problem in this particular case. His playbook does not validate for some reason he did not yet show in his question.

Comment: yes only localhost is available no need of the ssh. somehow managed to run playbook 
using role.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved at my end by using complete path for .yml file

> ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts myfirstplaybook.yml